# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I got the above exception when i trying to deploying my Application into tomcat. but the weird thing is , i tried with a simple main method and it's works fine. Any help please ???

I did the following:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "database=DBName;" + "user=UserName;" + "password=Password";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Comment: I think that the JDBC driver is not in the classpath. 
What are you using to build your project?

Comment: Look at one of the other hundred questions about this on this site. I just commented on another one just a minute ago.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add the jar file containing the class `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` to your war file's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Read [Tomcat Documentation about classpath](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) for clarification or just put the sqljdbc.jar in $CATALINA_HOME/lib to access it from all your applications.

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough you have JAR(sqlserverjdbc.jar) in build path You need to add the jar file containing the class. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver to your war file's WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

> May 15, 2014 3:09:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
>   SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>   java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
>   ...

It is quite puzzling because my web application has **WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc4.jar**.

From the error message, somehow the jar file is required by Tomcat too.

After I copy the jar file to **CATALINA_HOME/lib/sqljdbc4.jar**, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running a web app, you need to have the MS SQL Server driver--or the driver for any DB--stored in two places. Inside the app that becomes your WAR and then you need a second copy that is stored in the App Server's LIB directory. So, if you're running on Tomcat then you would put it /opt/tomcat/lib or C:\DEV\tomcat7\lib.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error running one of my java App from eclipse after uninstalled and re-installed tomcat.  I had to create a new Apache Tomcat Runtime from my Project.

From Eclipse Properties > Project Facets > Runtimes as per the following screenshot:

**Note:** Also, make sure you have a copy of the jdbc jar file into your tomcat library.
For example into: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib\mssql-jdbc-8.4.0.jre11.jar

[image: Project Facet New Runtime]

Enjoy!