# getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

Tags: classnotfoundexception

I have try many things but still getting same error. I am using jdK7 and Microsoft sql 2008 and eclipse,jar file is sqlijdc41.jar(4.1)
I have added the jar file using build path configure build path.

below is my code.

```
package com.daccess.captureimg;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class CaptureImage
 */
@WebServlet("/CaptureImage")
public class CaptureImage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public CaptureImage() {
        super(); }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:60700;databaseName=sampleprojectdb;user=sa;password=dsspl@123";


        try {
            System.out.println("connecting to the db");
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("driver get register");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("connected to the db");
            Statement stm=con.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate("insert into GPSLoaction1 values('123477.7','3467.7','gfasdgfghfsd')");

            System.out.println("Value insearted");
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {}
}
```

Below is the error in console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.daccess.captureimg.CaptureImage.doGet(CaptureImage.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please Help me where I am wrong.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?  I am getting the same exception (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210769/classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver?noredirect=1#comment56278852_34210769).

Comment: I had the same problem. Try [to add the driver library to Tomcats lib folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23674045/7090808).